# configuring search engine friendly url (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i want to understand at least abit on how the `.htaccess` works. i am using the `.htaccess` from zend framework (since thats what i use often)

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

1st line to set an environment variable, ok simple enuf, but what do the subsequent lines do? whats the `-s -l [NC,L]` etc for. from the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) i can see that

- `-s` - refers to a "regular file with a size". just curious is there a non-regular file?
- `-l` - refers to a symbolic link - whats that
- `-d` - refers to a directiory
- `REQUEST_FILENAME` - full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request
- `REQUEST_URI` - resource requested in the HTTP request line.

assuming i browsed to "`http://localhost/some/path/here`". what will `REQUEST_FILENAME` & `REQUEST_URI` equals to?

anyway, i interpret the rules currently as

- if the request is for a file with size OR
- if the request is for a link OR
- if the request is for a directory
- ... do something ...
- what does `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` do?
- then i guess route everything matching the rules above to index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL points to a real file/dir/link, serve the URL as is (the first RewriteRule line does not change the URL at all). Else, redirect to index.php.

Comment: does the 1st `RewriteRule` do anything then?

Comment: The first rule does not rewrite the URL, but it prevents that the second RewriteRule is used. Thus, any URL which matches the RewriteConds is *not* redirected to index.php.